# How do I get weights and biases from my model?

Tags: python, keras

I have a simple neural network, I need to get weights and biases from the model. I have tried a few approaches discussed before but I keep getting the out of bounds value error. Not sure how to fix this, or what I'm missing.

Network-

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

`model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]`

Error -
`IndexError: list index out of range`

This is what has been mentioned in a few questions,but I end up getting the out of bounds error for this.

I have another question, the index followed after`model.layers[]`, does it correspond to the layer?
For instance `model.layers[1]` gives the weights corresponding to the second layer, something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been there, I have been looking at my old code to see if I could remember how did I solved that issue.
What I did was to print the length of the `model.layer[index].get_weights()[X]` to figure out where keras was saving the weights I needed.
In my old code, `model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]` would return the biases, while `model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]` would return the actual weights.
In any case, take into account that there are layers which weights aren't saved (as they don't have weights), so if asking for `model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]` doesn't work, try with `model.layers[1].get_weights()[1]`, as I'm not sure about flatten layers, but I do know that dense layers should save their weights.

Comment: You can see the comments at the end of my old code if it helps you [https://github.com/abeagomez/CNN_triplet_loss_with_keras/blob/master/loading_weights.py]

Comment: You can also use this if you need the weights after every epoch [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473823/how-to-get-weight-matrix-of-one-layer-at-every-epoch-in-lstm-model-based-on-kera/46474642]

Comment: Hey,  thank you! So, say for example I run 5 epochs - the weights and biases that I get at the end would be basically the weights and biases for the 5th epoch obviously, right?

Also, I managed to get it to work - I think. ```model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]``` gives me a multidimensional array with subarrays with 10 elements each, and for ```model.layers[1].get_weights()[1]``` i get a single array...so I'm presuming the latter are the biases and the former are the weights(since I have 10 classes). Does it make sense?

Comment: @AdityaDas exactly!  the latter are the biases and the former are the weights and yes, the weights and biases you get at the end are from your last epoch, I only provided the extra info about in case you wanted to see how your weights look like during training :)

Answer (score 1):

The first layer (index 0) in your model is a `Flatten` layer, which does not have any weights, that's why you get errors.

To get the `Dense` layer, which is the second layer, you have to use index 1:

```
model.layers[1].get_weights()[1]
```

Comment: If we have multiple dense layers ? For the second dense layer (the third overall layer) will we be using  ```model.layers[2].get_weights()[2]```

Comment: @AdityaDas yes, layers are indexed just like any array

Answer (score 0):

Just `model.get_weights()`, you will get all the weights and bias of your model

Answer (score 0):

To get the weights and bias on a Keras sequential and for every iteration, you can do it as in the next example:

```
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(numHiddenNeurons, activation="tanh", input_dim=4, kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', 'mse', 'mae', 'mape'])
weightsBiasDict = {}
    
weightAndBiasCallback = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback \
            (on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: weightsBiasDict.update({epoch:model.get_weights()}))
    
# Fit the model
history= model.fit(X1, Y1, epochs=numIterations, batch_size=batch_size,  verbose=0, callbacks=weightAndBiasCallback)
```

weights and bias are accessible for every iteration on the dictionary `weightsBiasDict`

If you just need weights and bias values at the end of the training you can use
`model.layer[index].get_weights()[0]` for weights
and
`model.layer[index].get_weights()[1]` for biases
where `index` is the layer number on your network, starting at zero for the input layer.